# Javascript Error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' on the code below on line 3 in Chrome

```
function popup_shortlist(sel_id){
    var paramdata=Array();  
    paramdata[0]='<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>';
    paramdata[1]= $('#'+sel_id).val();

    var to_shortlist=false;
    var url='<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

    if($('#'+sel_id).attr('checked')){
        $("#alert_titleid").empty().html('Adding to Shortlist');
        $("#alert_msgid").empty().html('loading...');
        display_alert();  
        var rqpage='add to shortlist';  

        var arr_dataval = {
            action: 'instinct_controller',
            rqpage:rqpage,paramdata:paramdata
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl,arr_dataval ,function(data){
            $("#alert_msgid").empty().html(data);
        });

    }else{
        $("#alert_titleid").empty().html('Removing from Shortlist');
        $("#alert_msgid").empty().html('loading...');
        display_alert();  
        var rqpage='remove from shortlist';
        var arr_dataval = {
            action: 'instinct_controller',
            rqpage:rqpage,
            paramdata:paramdata
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl,arr_dataval ,function(data){
            $("#alert_msgid").empty().html(data);
        });                 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Double quotes vs single quotes, see the syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error, depending on what you want to do this line should be

```
paramdata[0]='<?php echo get_bloginfo(' + url + '); ?>';
```

or if you want to send the string 'url' to the get_bloginfo function you have to escape the single quotes

```
paramdata[0]='<?php echo get_bloginfo(\'url\'); ?>';
```

my guess is that you want to do the first one.

Same thing in the following line:

```
var url='<?php echo bloginfo(' + url + '); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
```

Comment: Actually, that is PHP, so it should be *`.`* instead of `+` : `paramdata[0]='<?php echo get_bloginfo(' . $url . '); ?>';`, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want paramdata[0] to be a straight string, no concatenation involved? In that case, use double quotes on the outside, or it treats the single quotes around `'url'` as ending a string and looks for a `+` or a `;`.

```
function popup_shortlist(sel_id){
    var paramdata=Array();  
        paramdata[0]="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>";
```