# jQuery - Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does this error mean? `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"`

I get it in this:

```
 $('#prepare_payment’).attr('disabled','true');
     jQuery('#prepare_payment_form :text').each(function() {
     jQuery(this).attr('disabled', 'true');
 });
```

And this as well:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

   if(response.indexOf(“Error: “) != -1) {
      $('#paypal_error').css('display', 'block');
      $('#paypal_error').html(response);
      $('#prepare_payment').removeAttr(disabled”);
      jQuery(“#prepare_payment_form :text”).each(function() {
         jQuery(this).removeAttr(“disabled”);
      });
      return false;
   }
```

Can anyone tell me what the error means and why it's appearing?

Comment: You are using weird quotes...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725291/javascript-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier

Comment: What are these ...`“ ”`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change all `’`, `“` or `”` to `"` or `'` in your code, so change:

```
'#prepare_payment’
“Error: “
disabled”
“#prepare_payment_form :text”
“disabled”
```

to:

```
'#prepare_payment'
'Error: '
'disabled'
'#prepare_payment_form :text'
'disabled'
```

Final code look like:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
   if(response.indexOf('Error: ') != -1) {
      $('#paypal_error').css('display', 'block');
      $('#paypal_error').html(response);
      $('#prepare_payment').removeAttr('disabled');
      jQuery('#prepare_payment_form :text').each(function() {
         jQuery(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      });
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using two types of quotes to delimit the same string. If you look at:

```
$('#prepare_payment’
```

you see that you start the string with the `'`  delimiter and end it with the ` character (which is not a string delimiter). There are two valid string delimiters: ' and ". For each string you can chose which of those two delimiters to use, but you can't mix them.

So, your bug can be fixed using either one of the following two options:

```
$('#prepare_payment'
$("#prepare_payment"
```

And in the `jQuery(“#prepare_payment_form :text”)` statement you are using `“` and `”` characters, which should either be a ' or " character:

```
jQuery('#prepare_payment_form :text')
jQuery("#prepare_payment_form :text")
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes should be `'` or `"` not `“`

```
  jQuery("#prepare_payment_form :text").each(function() {
     jQuery(this).removeAttr("disabled");
  })
```

Same for this also, `’` is invalid

```
$('#prepare_payment')
```

Also I assume that the `$.post()` is closed properly